# Multiline edittext enter character with json android

Tags: android, json, string, android-edittext, newline

I have the following problem and hope that anyone can help

1- I have multiline edittext allow user to enter data with keyboard enter,
2- Then when I take the value edittext.getText().toString() and make JSON object out of it, the JSON is not formated

it is like

```
{

  "ItemDescription": "Yyyyy
  Yyyyyy
  Yyyyyyyyy
  Yyyyyyyyyyyy
  Yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

}
```

althought it should be like

```
{"ItemDescription": "Yyyyy\nYyyyyy\nYyyyyyyyy\nYyyyyyyyyyyy\nYyyyyyyyyyyyyy"}
```

can anyone help please

Comment: The string in which you are storing data use this jsonString.replaceAll(" ", "");

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what do you want. `Next line symbol` either exists or not. How to represent it depends on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "\\\\n");
```

This will replace `new line character` with `\n` string.